# Event inside Resource result in Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, telerik, datatemplate

I got an `Usercontrol` with a `DataTemplate` inside its `resources`, containing a `Treeview`.

This `Treeview` uses `HierarchicalDataTemplate` to show easy item type correct.
This works perfectly. I then added a `ContextMenu`. Now my problem is that as soon as I use an `event`

```
 <Telerik:RadContextMenu x:Name="radContextMenu" Opened="radContextMenu_Opened" >
```

This results in an

> Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object

If i remove the Opened event it works perfectly. But I need a way to see which item the ContextMenu is for.
I can use commands without any problems, but I still needs to know which items its for.
I have testet with adding events to other parts of the treeview and the result is the same error, just after the program is started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Answer my own question. 
To Solve the `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` error

I had to move all code from the resources into another usercontrol. 
So my Ressource now looks like this.

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ContentTemplate">
        <view:UserControlTreeView/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This works without any error.

Comment: I had the same problem even though I hadn't coded an event.  Building the project fixed me up.